# Send APi key and secret key in CURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to convert the line below to be used with PHP whilst also learning how to use CURL!

```
$ curl -X POST -d 'key=YOUR_KEY&secret=YOUR_SECRET' "https://api.example.co.uk/authenticate" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Bellow is what I have so far, however I keep getting HTTP ERROR 403 UnauthorizedException accessing service error, so I think the key and secret and not being sent correctly.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.example.co.uk/authenticate",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"key\": \"MYKEY\",\"secret\": \"MYSECRET\"}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Your Content-Type header says you were sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but the actual data is JSON instead.

Comment: I was going by what the original line from the documentation said. Is this not correct?

Comment: What original line, are you referring to the curl command you quoted? That clearly shows `key=YOUR_KEY&secret=YOUR_SECRET`, does it not?

Comment: But it also says "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded". I have tried changing it to say "Content-Type: application/json" however I still get the same error.

Comment: Well does the documentation _say_ that it accepts JSON?

Comment: Documentation says - …with a "x-www-form-urlencoded" key/secret pair (this will be supplied to you)

This will generate an access token with an expiration timestamp as a JSON payload.

Comment: Pretty sure with "JSON payload" they are referring to the _response_ you will get back here (can't see anything else make sense in the given context.) So keep the header as is, and send `key=YOUR_KEY&secret=YOUR_SECRET`.

Comment: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ <-- great tool

Comment: @CBroe keepy getting HTTP ERROR 403 UnauthorizedException accessing service: [Unable to create new Token. Invalid key or secret supplied].

Comment: @Shlomtzion Okay, So I tried the tool, however I keep getting the error above, so would I be right in thinking there's an issue with the key/secret I have?

Comment: Sounds like it, yes.

Comment: @Harry mmm... Not sure - you received a code and a secret yes from the company the API belongs to yes? and these work when you curl? or in postman or similar? or are they not working for you there also? if it works in curl than there's nothing wrong with the credentials ...  so ... is it working on curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this tool as it save so much time - https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Generated this:

```
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.example.co.uk/authenticate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "key=YOUR_KEY&secret=YOUR_SECRET");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to use an array for header variable and assign api_key or secret key through array and pass that variable into curls->CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

```
// Collection object
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    
 $headers = array(
         "APIKEY: PUT_HERE_API_KEY",
         "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
         "Accept: text/xml"
     );
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlreq);
    $result = curl_exec($ch); // execute
    $result;
   //show response
    curl_close($ch);
```